# Getting issue while running Bot Framework Orchestrator command from Azure Bot App Service Console

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-appservice

I am trying to run some commands from the in-built console provided in the Microsoft Azure App service, but facing an issue.

As mentioned in the screenshot, the command needs a Y/N input here.

"Help us improve products by allowing Microsoft to collect anonymous command and flags usage: (Y/N):"

But before providing it, the control is passed to a new line, which doesn't accept the input.

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Please help me out here to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Make sure [bf orchestrator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/blob/main/packages/orchestrator/README.md#bf-orchestratorbasemodelget) command is working and shows all available orchestrator commands

> bf orchestrator

We are able to pass and find the snapshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Hi, yes I tried running this command, facing similar issue. It goes to the next line without taking the response for Y/N. I have edited the ques and added the screenshot for the same there.

Comment: We couldn't reproduce this, please raise an issue in the following link. https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues